# Keyboard settings randomly stop working often

Tags: drivers, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have a Microsoft Surfacebook 2 running Ubuntu with the Jakeday kernel. I have some custom keybindings, such as my Capslock functioning as an additional hyper key, my scrolling direction being inverted, etc. However, sometimes when I'm using my laptop, my keybindings will just randomly turn off, capslock will start acting as caps again, scrolling will stop being inverted. I am able to fix it by rebooting my laptop, but this is really inconvenient to have to keep doing.

I am also able to cause this bug on demand by detaching the screen from the base, which suggests to me that this has something to do with the screen's connection to the base cutting out. Any guesses?

Is there another way to fix it without rebooting my laptop, like forcing the keyboard drivers to start up again?

Comment: How did you set the custom keybindings?

Comment: @Quasímodo gnome-tweaks